# Выполнение определенного действия строго после того как отработает функция

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some code...
    func(elementId);
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.scrollIntoView();
});

function func(elementId) {
    var element = $('#' + elementId);
    var parents = element.parents('.panel-collapse');
    $.each(parents, function (key, object) {
        //some code...
    });
}
```

Задача в том, что бы после того как отработает функция `func` проскролить экран к нужному элементу. На сколько я понимаю, в данном варианте код выполняется асинхронно. Т.е. не дождавжись завершения функции `func`  происходит переход к следующим шагам.

Comment: а где асинхроность

Comment: самый простой способ "в лоб" - сделать тоже самое что у вас сделано в 4-ой с конца строке - добавить callback вторым аргументом и в него сунуть всё что надо сделать после асинхронной операции. но по хорошему почитайте, например, про промисы https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо за ответ! Я читал про промисы, и более того уже больше часа вожусь с ними, но никак не получается. Не могли бы вы на моем примере показать как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const func = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var element = $('#' + elementId);
    var parents = element.parents('.panel-collapse');
    $.each(parents, function (key, object) {
        //some code...
    });
    resolve(true);


    /// если ошибка

    resolve(false)
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    //some code...
    func.then(v => {
        if (v) {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            element.scrollIntoView();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ.  Я сейчас понял что не совсем корректно задал свой вопрос, но постольку по скольку вы уже дали ответ, и он весьма ценен, я не стал изменять\удалять вопрос, а создал новый с более точным описанием(в общем то и задача получается уже другая). Загляните суда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932093 , может есть идеи? Надеюсь это не противоречит правилам :)